# How to overarchingly apply "utf-8" to opening csv/txt files in pandas dataframe?

Tags: encoding, text-files, python-3.5

I am trying to import data from text files from particular file path, but am getting error `'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xa5 in position 18: invalid start byte`

My question is there anyway I can apply "utf-8" encoding to all the text files(about 20 others) I will have to open eventually so I can prevent the above error?

Code:

```
import pandas as pd
filelist = [r'D:/file1',r'D:/file2']
print (len((pd.concat([pd.read_csv(item, names=[item[:-4]]) for item in filelist],axis=1))))
```

also open to any suggestions if I am doing something wrong.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [UnicodeDecodeError: ('utf-8' codec) while reading a csv file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33819557/unicodedecodeerror-utf-8-codec-while-reading-a-csv-file)

Comment: @knanne yes it does, as well as the below answer selected. Thank you so much for reaching out and providing the link!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not aware of solution to automatically convert encoding to utf-8 in python.

Alternatively, you can find out what the encoding is, and read it accordingly. Then write to file in utf-8.

[this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33819765/5356898) worked well for my files (credit [maxnoe](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3838691/maxnoe))

```
import chardet
import pandas as pd

with open('filename.csv', 'rb') as f:
    result = chardet.detect(f.read())  # or readline if the file is large

pd.read_csv('filename.csv', encoding=result['encoding'])
```

don't forget to `pip install chardet`

if you now write file using `pd.to_csv()`, pandas default is to encode in utf-8