# Unicode DecodeError while concatenating

Tags: pandas, parsing

I am trying to train my model and i have csv file and one gz file, which was generated earlier. I am getting this error as mentioned below and not sure what is wrong.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Model.py", line 87, in <module>
    data = pd.concat([pd.read_csv(log)])
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py", line 678, in parser_f
    return _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py", line 440, in _read
    parser = TextFileReader(filepath_or_buffer, **kwds)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py", line 787, in __init__
    self._make_engine(self.engine)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py", line 1014, in _make_engine
    self._engine = CParserWrapper(self.f, **self.options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py", line 1708, in __init__
    self._reader = parsers.TextReader(src, **kwds)
  File "pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx", line 539, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader.__cinit__
  File "pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx", line 767, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._get_header
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x8b in position 1: invalid start byte
```

Mycode:

```
for foo in range(0,1):
    # Read dataframe
    #data = pd.concat([pd.read_csv(log.replace('0',str(idx),1)) for idx in range(5)])
    log = path + 'train_features/log_.csv'

    test_log = path + 'test_features/log_features.gz'
    data = pd.concat([pd.read_csv(log)])
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
data = pd.read_csv(log, encoding = "utf-8")
```

Although I don't understand why you need the for loop or [pd.concat](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html)

If you don't know your type of encoding, try: this:

```
import chardet

with open(log, 'rb') as f:
    result = chardet.detect(f.read())  # or readline if the file is large


data = pd.read_csv(log, encoding=result['encoding'])
```

[source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33819557/unicodedecodeerror-utf-8-codec-while-reading-a-csv-file/33819765)

Comment: Thanks, But after doing this still the error persists

Comment: Try `encoding = 'ISO-8859-1'` or `encoding=’cp1252′`. It really depends on the encoding you have.