# pandas read_csv fails on specific row returning UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, matlab, sas

Pandas read_csv() returns UnicodeDecodeError on some specific rows.
If I use `nrows=n1` it works without any error. But when I use `nrows=n2 (>n1)` somehow it returns
`UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xb0 in position 12: invalid start byte`

It worked fine before, but at some point it keeps me returning the error.
Sometimes it works again when I reboot the computer, but only for the first time I try to call it.

Tried read_csv with and without encoding option. Also tried error_bad_lines=False.

This is driving me crazy. Any ideas?
If this is related to system issue, at least I want to know how to get the row number of problematic row.

(I exported table from MATLAB with encoding specified as `etf-8` (also tried `CP949`, which is my system's default encoding). Importing from SAS wass successful.)

Comment: Which encoding options did you try? You can try to let python detect the encoding, and provide that to `read_csv` as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33819557/unicodedecodeerror-utf-8-codec-while-reading-a-csv-file/33819765#33819765).

Comment: tried utf-8, cp949, or let the python to determine as you suggested. All failed miserably. Haven’t tried chardet yet. Thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: Use `chardet.detect`, or any text editor able to read your file and tell you what encoding it uses, or one of the many online tools that let you detect your encoding...

Comment: Don't be subtle: try `encoding='latin1'` in `read_csv` ;)

Answer (score 0):

When using [`pandas.read_csv`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html) there are various parameters one can pass. One of them is the `encoding`, which will allow the translation of characters. If one is curious to know more about encodings, [this](https://realpython.com/python-encodings-guide/) can be a good place to start.

As there are a lot of encodings and don't have access to OP's data, one might want to look [at this page](https://docs.python.org/3/library/codecs.html#standard-encodings), where one can find Python standard encodings.

Then, assuming one's file is called `data.csv`, one will have to use as follows

```
import pandas as pd

pd.read_csv('data.csv', encoding='iso-8859-1')  # iso-8859-1 is for Western Europe
```

Again, the list of encodings is vast, so I recommend OP to adjust depending on OP's use case.

From `pandas` version 1.3.0, argument `encoding_errors` was added ([see this PR](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/pull/39777)). This one influences how encoding errors are handled. See [here a list of possible values](https://docs.python.org/3/library/codecs.html#error-handlers).

If one wants to `replace`, considering the enconding used above, then the following should do the work

```
import pandas as pd

pd.read_csv('data.csv', encoding='iso-8859-1', encoding_errors='replace')
```